# Libman - How to install dependencies of installed library

Tags: asp.net-core, visual-studio-code, unpkg, libman

I am using **Libman** - **Asp Core** - **VsCode**

I Installed **Semantic-ui** which needs **jQuery**,**Popper** and etc.

Is there a way that **Libman** install it's dependencies automatically while installing a library ?

Like what **npm** does.

Answer (score 3):

No.  Libman does not track dependencies, it is not a package manager.  It provides a simplified experience for placing deployment-ready libraries into your project.  For a full package manager feature set, you should use a proper package manager like NPM.

Answer (score 1):

If *libman.json* has the dependencies listed but they aren't in the lib folder, one solution is to right click the project -> add -> Client Side Library and then add a library already listed in *libman.json*.  This will add all libraries from *libman.json*.  It will create a new entry in *libman.json* which can then be removed.  Not ideal, not pretty, but it works.